# C# - generic List and ConvertAll() Method, how does it internally work?

Tags: c#, list, generics, convertall

from some code I found in Sacha Barbers free mvvm framework chinch I saw this:

```
return new DispatcherNotifiedObservableCollection<OrderModel>(
                    DataAccess.DataService.FetchAllOrders(
                        CurrentCustomer.CustomerId.DataValue).ConvertAll(
                            new Converter<Order, OrderModel>(
                                  OrderModel.OrderToOrderModel)));
```

`FetchAllOrders` returns a `List<Order>` for a certain customerID.
This list is converted to a `List<OrderModel>` or in other words `List<OrderViewModel>`.

How can that happen? What must be the requirements/conditions, that every property of the Order object in the `List<Order>` is converted into a property of the `OrderModel` ?

Comment: I can not help myself but with Chrome browser not all text I wrote in the main post is shown ?? So I paste here the rest so the sentence above makes sense:

FetchAllOrders return a List<Order> for a certain customerID.
This list is converted to a List<OrderModel> or in other words List<OrderViewModel>.

Comment: I've just edited the post to make the `<>` code visible, use the back tick (see the information on the right side of the page when you click on `edit`. Also check the source of the post now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make that code a bit more readable:

```
List<Order> orders =
    DataAccess.DataService.FetchAllOrders(CurrentCustomer.CustomerId.DataValue);

Converter<Order, OrderModel> converter =
    new Converter<Order, OrderModel>(OrderModel.OrderToOrderModel);

List<OrderModel> orderModels = orders.ConvertAll(converter);

return new DispatcherNotifiedObservableCollection<OrderModel>(orderModels);
```

**What happens here?**

1. The code fetches all orders from the data store and stores them in a List<T>.
2. The code creates a delegate of type Converter<TInput, TOutput> that converts from a single Order to a single OrderModel.
3. The code converts all orders to order models by applying the converter to each order.
4. The code returns a DispatcherNotifiedObservableCollection<T> with the list of converted values.

**How does it work?**

Basically, what ConvertAll does here, is equivalent to this:

```
List<OrderModel> orderModels = new List<OrderModel>(orders.Count);
for (int i = 0; i < orders.Count; i++)
{
    orderModels[i] = OrderModel.OrderToOrderModel(orders[i]);
}
```

Does that answer your question?

Comment: it answers the question yes and no ;-) what the code is doing, but not why ;-)